# Youtube-dl @ want to download only the playlist (list of file name) to a text file

Tags: youtube-dl

I want to download only the File list (File names in a playlits) to a output text file using YouTube dl.
Q

Answer (score 1):

Have a easy method. use this code

```
youtube-dl -i -o %(playlist_index)s-%(title)s --get-filename --skip-download  https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLpQLftDPSfXzLsww0KvSRerT00G4frW7L > log.txt
```

According to this code you will get the log.txt file as follows

[image]

`-i` or `--ignore-errors` => continue download videos, skip unavilable videos
After the `-o` you can create the template as you want with the file name.

- If you only need the file name, use this section  `%(title)s`
- If you only need the file name and playlist index number, use this
  section `%(playlist_index)s-%(title)s`
- extension if needed `%(playlist_index)s-%(title)s.%(ext)s`
- uploader if needed `%(playlist_index)s-%(uploader)s%(title)s.%(ext)s`

This way you can customize the code. You can read the "readme file" in youtube-dl [here](https://github.com/ytdl-org/youtube-dl/blob/master/README.md#readme)